NextUI dom nested button warning with <Accordion />
I'm trying to add a button as the startContent property inside an AccordionItem in in NextUI. The problem is that the AccordionItem uses  as an implementation but I really have to add a button functionality inside startContent property, which is nesting two button tags under the hood. Is it possible to fix this annoying warning?
the warning message in dom
here's my code
      <Accordion
        isCompact
        showDivider={false}
        variant='splitted'
        className='relative px-0'
        itemClasses={{
          base: 'relative container shadow-none gap-10 rounded-small',
          titleWrapper: 'rounded-sm',
          title: 'text-medium font-bold text-black',
        }}>
        {faqs.slice(0, displayCount).map((faq, i) => (
          <AccordionItem
            key={i}
            title={faq.title}
            aria-label={faq.title}
            startContent={
              <Tooltip showArrow size='lg' content='орчуулга үзэх' placement='top-start'>
                <Button
                  isIconOnly
                  radius='full'
                  className='bg-transparent'
                  size='sm'
                  onClick={() => showInterpreter(faq)}>
                  <FaHandsAslInterpreting className='text-primary w-7 h-7' />
                </Button>
              </Tooltip>
            }
            className='!bg-primary/5 !px-6 !py-3 !shadow-none p-0'
            classNames={{ base: 'p-0' }}>
            <div className='flex gap-3'>
              <InterpreterIcon color='#58585E' className='flex-shrink-0' />
              <p className=''>{faq.description}</p>
            </div>
          </AccordionItem>
        ))}
      </Accordion>

I tried not using the  component but the onclick callback is no longer functional

Please don't take screenshots of your code and errors. Instead you should include them in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]
